# Bounty e-mail notification sender is Stack Overflow rather than MSO/SE

Tags: bug, bounties, email

The *Bounty Grace Period Started* e-mail's "from" display name is Stack Overflow for a bounty started on Meta Stack Overflow.

[image: e-mail header]

It's rendered as follows:

```
MIME-Version: 1.0
X-Mailer: MailBee.NET 7.0.4.334
From: "Stack Overflow" <do-not-reply@meta.stackoverflow.com>
```

However, all other e-mails I get from Stack Exchange have a display name of Stack Exchange (this is the MSO newsletter):

```
MIME-Version: 1.0
X-Mailer: MailBee.NET 7.0.4.334
From: "Stack Exchange" <do-not-reply@stackexchange.com>
```

I would expect the notification to be from MSO if the bounty is on MSO or from SE like everything else. The current sender is confusing because I didn't have a bounty on SO, but this is what is displayed in my inbox.

I also notice that the sender domain is different, which is a little strange... but it's not as obvious.